# What changes to my network settings in Windows 7 can I make to achieve lower latency for gaming?

Tags: windows-7, tcp, gaming, latency

What changes to my network settings in Windows 7 can I make to achieve lower latency for gaming? I have heard of changing TCP settings in the registry, but I have also heard conflicting information on whether it actually works in Windows 7 or only Windows XP, and I'm not sure what registry values would work best.

Comment: What latency are you seeing? What state/country is the server located in and what state/country are you located in? (When you ask, "how can I get to work faster", the answer is very different if you're currently driving a hundred miles than if you're currently jogging one mile.)

Comment: I'm in California and the server is somewhere in North America.  I haven't actually measured the latency but I would guess it is somewhere in the range of 100-300ms, although latencies can get up to 900ms for some packets when my ISP is having issues (the 900 figure is from traceroutes to google).

Comment: If you haven't measured this yet, how are you going to determine if anything we suggest is better? Also, we need to know what it is now to see if it is already on the low-side. A traceroute to Google doesn't help, we need the numbers from site to site.

Answer (score 0):

Set your MTU value to 576.

This is easily accomplished in Windows by executing the following command:

> for /l %A in (1,1,100) do netsh interface ipv4 set interface "%A" mtu=576

The more hops between end nodes, the more this will help. If your latency is due to slow network equipment processing speed, the benefit will be slight to none.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what MTU is and how this change would affect latency (and anything else)